# Close <ul> each 8 <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to close the element `<ul>` each 8 elements `<li>`. Someone can help me?

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyDwHNKX0Ti4HYrJZ9Mf-mMIZxVU5JwiLVI&channelId=UCxRGbboDO9bCYd651YpIZuw&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50',
  function(data){
    var x = 0;
    var breakList = '';

    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      x++;

      if(x == 8){ //break ul if is 8
        x =0;
        breakList = 'break';
      }

      $('ul').append('<li class='+breakList+'>' + item.id.videoId + '</li>');

      breakList = '';
    });     

});
```

I tried break `<ul>` in the code but i can't.

Comment: Can you show us also the html code? You have a small bug when adding the class; you forgot the "":  $('ul').append('<li class="'+breakList+'">' + item.id.videoId + '</li>'); You don't need x also because you already have the value inside i. Otherwise your code seems to be work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by close the `<ul>` element?  Your code as it is should work fine provided you have a `<ul>` tag to append to.  Also, you probably want to use a specific ID for your list, in case you have more than one ul element.  Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/aghzznwx/

Comment: Is requirement to only append eight `li` elements to `ul` element ?

Comment: @AlexSuleap I will make a carousel's movie and I need paged it, so each 8 video I want break my list and start another list with more 8 videos.

Comment: @AdamKonieska I would like start a new list each 8 videos, because I will make a carousel's videos, and wach 8 video start a new list.

Comment: @guest271314 I want 8 video in list. If I have 24 videos I need 3 list with 8 video.

Comment: @Deise Is `data.items` an array ?

Comment: @Deise See post. What is purpose of `breaklist` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator to create a new list every 8 items.

Something like this would work:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyDwHNKX0Ti4HYrJZ9Mf-mMIZxVU5JwiLVI&channelId=UCxRGbboDO9bCYd651YpIZuw&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50',
function(data){
var counter = 0;
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    if(i % 8 == 0) {
    counter++;
    $('#youTubeContainer').append('<ul id="list'+counter+'"></ul>');
}
  $('ul#list'+counter).append('<li>' + item.id.videoId + '</li>');

});
```

});

Also, you probably want to give your list an ID and append the results to a specific ID.

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/aghzznwx/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand but I need 50 videos and each 8 video break list because I will make a carousel's video.

Comment: @Deise ah, I understand now.  I updated my answer and the JS fiddle so it creates a new `<ul>` every 8 videos.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.slice()` to copy `data` array; `while` loop containing `Array.prototype.splice()` with parameters `0, 8` to remove indexes between `0` and `8` while items remain in copied array

```js
var data = $.map(Array(27), function(item, index) {
  return {"id":{"videoId":index}}
});

var copy = data.slice(0);

while (copy.length) {
  var curr = copy.splice(0, 8);
  var ul = $("<ul>", {css:{border:"2px solid olive"}});
  curr.forEach(function(item) {
    ul.append($("<li>", {
      html: item.id.videoId
    }))
  });
  $("body").append(ul);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```